# Custom Content Type as List Column

Tags: 2010, content-type, site-column

Is it possible to create a custom list column whose type is a custom content type? Not just a column from that content type, but the whole item itself, or even a list of that content type?

My goal is to create a hierarchy of content types, for example:

My Prospect Content Type
-> Has column : Client (of type My Client Content Type)

My Client Content Type
-> Has column : Associations (a list of type My Association Content Type)

UPDATES:

I ended up trying out and liking the solution presented in [this article](http://blog.medhat.ca/2007/10/simulate-parent-child-relationship-in.html).

The gist is that I create a content type "My Parent Content Type" which inherits from the built-in Folder content type. I create a second content type called "My Child Content Type" which simply inherits from Item. Then, I create a list which can hold items of both of these content types.

Next, I add a My Parent Content Type to this list, navigate to the item I just created, then create a My Child Content Type item within that folder. It works well enough, I think. The only trick is, I need to make sure the site users only create new items in this manner.

I would like to constrain the New Item button to only allow creation of My Child Content Type items within the context of a My Parent Content Type folder, but I suppose that is another question related to Ribbon modification :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the list that you would want to show the related information, you would create a lookup column to your list that has the prospect content type associated to it. In the configuration of the lookup column, you can select additional columns from the list item to bring over into the list.

Comment: I want to do more than this though. I want to be able to navigate from parent item of content type A to child item of content type B, where B is represented as a column of A.

Comment: That isn't possible afaik, you'd need to roll your own. You could use the above approach to store the information, but you'd have to roll your own UI to surface it how you want.

Comment: @udog The good part is that if you click on a lookup column, you will see the entire item with all properties without leaving the original list.

Comment: Is it possible to navigate to the item (via a link) stored in a lookup column?